# Difference between web services and JMS

Tags: web-services, jms

I am new into these topics. JMS and web services seem to have same purpose but I feel there is lot more differences? Can someone provide the differences? And when are these technologies applied?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between JMS and Web Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624275/difference-between-jms-and-web-service)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements and your architecture you can use both, they can even be used together.

JMS is a messaging standard specifically for Java EE. So it is better to compare Message Passing and Web Service.

A good idea is to read on wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

A similar discussion took place here: [Difference between JMS and Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624275/difference-between-jms-and-web-service)

As an example, in the case my architecture was exposing to the world an interface, I would most likely offer web services. If however my architecture was to connect with a fast producing events module over a secure connection, I would use message passing.