# SOA means only web services?

Tags: web-services, soa, esb

As per Service-Oriented Architecture (SOA) definition, an architectural style that supports service-orientation.

Does that mean only **web services (SOAP and REST)** are treated as part/backbone of SOA? What about messaging services?

Comment: If someone only reads the title of your question, the classic answer is going to be no! Some people take a SOA definition (one of the many and many going around) and talks about services in a abstract way (never mention about web services, they could be whatever type you could imagine). So for them the answer would be: the backbone are services (and then define what is a service). In this case, i don't know if you talk about messaging services and think of a event-driven architecture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture).

Comment: @PatrickLC : I'm talking about the JMS service (topic/queue)

Comment: Now it's clear for me, JMS works at the transport layer (as HTTP), i think you could take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624275/difference-between-jms-and-web-service

Comment: I have done SOA with custom TCP/IP servers running google protocol buffers. SOA is an architecture concept normally implemented via SOAP/REST services but you could do it via email if you liked pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No and yes.**

A webservice can be designed in a service orientated way, but a "service" (SOA) describes functionality, a bundle of business logic.

Service orientated architecture means, you have different systems, different users, and the way you implement your business focuses on the whole beeing a service.

The former (SOA) is something abstract, a paradigm, a commitment on **how** to implement something, the latter is technology (REST, SOAP, ...).

In conjunction with webservices, the "how to" is often described using *WS-Business Process Execution Language* (short: BPEL). It is used to orchestrate providers and consumers and allows high-traffic processes to scale in the cloud.

Consider your bank, processing many business steps per second in a very standardized fashion; using standard services like transfering money from one account to another.

Talking about Java and JMS, Oracle has a tutorial up: [This example shows the steps to create a simple JMS queue in WebLogic Server 11g for testing purposes.](https://blogs.oracle.com/soaproactive/entry/how_to_create_a_simple)